# The program executable file marked as read-only

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, file-permissions

I was reading wikipedia on Segmentation Faults and come through following code and statements.

```
int main(void)
 {
     char *s = "hello world";
     *s = 'H';
 }
```

> When the program containing this code is compiled, the string "hello
>   world" is placed in the section of the program executable file marked
>   as read-only; when loaded, the operating system places it with other
>   strings and constant data in a read-only segment of memory. When
>   executed, a variable, s, is set to point to the string's location, and
>   an attempt is made to write an H character through the variable into
>   the memory, causing a segmentation fault. Compiling such a program
>   with a compiler that does not check for the assignment of read-only
>   locations at compile time.

My question is on file permission i.e, when executables marked as read-only and when read and write
 and so on ?

I want to know all about file permissions.Can we change the file permission explicitly?

Comment: When it says file, does it mean stack over here?

Comment: File access permissions and memory access permissions within a running program are not related.  Marking an executable program as writable will not cause its text pages to be mapped read/write; conversely, marking it read only will not cause its data pages to be unexpectedly mapped read only.

Comment: I'm not sure how file permissions are relevant -- the wiki article is referring to permissions of *pages of memory*.  It may be possible to change page permissions in a system-specific way, such as `mprotect()` on POSIX systems.

Comment: here file is executable file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"hello world" is stored in a read-only section of *memory*. The ability to write to a given part of an executable's memory is not related to the ability to write to the executable on disk.

Comment: Not all of the executable's memory is read-only. For example, if you have something like `i=0; i=2`, then `i` will be stored in read-write memory (assuming the compiler doesn't optimize it into one assignment).

Comment: @IndieProgrammer By default, yes.  It's an attribute of a loadable segment in an executable; by default text (= code) segments are marked read-only, but you can override this.  The advantages of read-only segments aren't just protection from bad code, but also that they can more easily be shared between the memory images of multiple running instances.

Comment: thanks '@geekosaur' and '@Patrick' for your great views on the topic.

Answer (score 2):

There are 3 unrelated concepts you are talking in this question:

- file attributes (supported by some OS, i.e. Windows) - one of them is read-only. Manages how normally files will be opened, user with permissions to modify file can change file attributes at will.
- file permissions (supported by most OS). If given user have permission to access/modify, and in some systems execute the file.
- memory protection attributes on pages of memory. Supported by most OS that implement virtual memory. Each page (i.e. 4Kb block) of memory gets set of attributes (i.e. read, write, execute) that are set and enforced by memeory management part of OS together with CPU. Most modern CPUs directly use this page attribute to verify memory operations.

I.e. on Windows you can use [VirtualProtect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366898%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function to specify what attributes given memory block allocated in your program's address space should have.

Answer (score 0):

String literals in C programming are const char* by default even if you typecast it (char*). Since it's a const(ant) you can't write to it. You could use something like this;

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main (void)
{
    char s[12];
    strcpy(s, "hello world");
    s[0] = 'H';

    printf("%s\n", s);

    return 0;
}
```